# Android facebook integration with facebook sdk 4.6.0

Tags: android, facebook

After successfully login into the facebook, I am getting the message as shown in the screen shot.
         [image: ERROR MESSAGE after login]

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: please check logcat i think u got any error

Comment: If Internet is slow, then I got error. Otherwise i don't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem when i was testing on a real device using different facebook users.
Then i tried on the emulator (on the same computer i created the hashkey) and 
used the same facebook user i created the app ID, the problem disappeared. 
I think facebook blocks us when we user anothe FB user or another PC and this "Helpful" message pops up!